# Creating array with calculating the number of uppercase and delete specified char by copying to second array

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling, char

I am creating a program that ask user to enter 21 chars in an array then the program calculate the number of **uppercase** letters.

The second function that the program does is that he delete a specified char **"$"** by copying the elements of the array to a second array.

Example: 
The user will enter 21 character
`thisi$sATe$ST`
the system will

1. First calculate the number of UPPERCASE chars
2. Second will delete "$" from the array by copying the character to a
   second array

My code display this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:375)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:269)
at test4.test4.main(Question4.java:21)
```

How to fix it?

## This is my code

```
package test4

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] a = new String[]{ "A", "b", "C", "$", "$", "$", "d", "s", "w", "t", "Z",
                "r", "I", "o", "A", "b", "C", "$", "$", "$", "d", "s", "w", "t" };

        String[] b = new String[a.length];
        int num = 0;
        for(int i =0; i<a.length; i++){

            if(Character.isUpperCase(i)){
                num++;
            }
            if(Arrays.asList(a).contains("$")){

                Arrays.asList(a).remove("$");
                b[i] =a[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("number os uperCase is: " + num);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("this is the new Array: " + Arrays.toString(b));

    }
}
```

Anyone can help me ??

Comment: Why `T1.length - 1`? You'll only ever copy 20 elements, not 21, given that you test for i being _strictly_ lower. More generally there are many things wrong with your code and even your explanation is unclear. Please give sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: because when i use it without -1 it give an error

Comment: It won't give an error only in that case; it will throw an exception if an empty string is given to `sc.nextLine()` as soon as the first entry

Comment: i tried without -1 it give this error                              **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:694)
 at exam2Programing2_28_12_2010.Question4.main(Question4.java:19)**

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem using `regex`, ex:

```
String in = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])").matcher(s);
int c = 0;

while(m.find()){
    c++;
}

System.out.println("Uppercases:" + c);
System.out.println("Result:" + in.replace("$", ""));
```